# I have an MVC app in dev and use bootstrap tab widget which has always worked until i updated jquery from 3.5.0.1 to 3.5.1 now they do not work

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Nothing else has changed and when i go back to an earlier version of my app and install all updates again thru nuget with the exception of the jquery update everything works fine again, I did notice that with the new version installed the tab panel selected appears in the url but not in the previous version which works